Apache reverse proxy 503 custom page not working properly
I am trying to setup a custom 503 error page on my website. I am using this apache configuration.
# Exclude the Maintenance directory from being proxied
 ProxyPass /Maintenance !

# ProxyPass other requests to the backend server
ProxyPass / https://local*********:***/
ProxyPassReverse / https://local********:***/

# Set the custom error document for 503 errors
ErrorDocument 503 /Maintenance/index.html

The issue is that the custom page is not able to render its content properly. As the index.html page require images and css.
I am getting 503 error on other pages which require to generate images and css.
[Mon Apr 22 05:15:11.279807 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 3662468:tid 22997273540352] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: https: attempt to connect to**************** failed
[Mon Apr 22 05:15:11.279841 2024] [proxy_http:error] [pid 3662468:tid 22997273540352] ************ AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: ************
[Mon Apr 22 05:15:12.881465 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 3662468:tid 22997271439104] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: https: attempt to connect to*************** failed
[Mon Apr 22 05:15:12.881502 2024] [proxy_http:error] [pid 3662468:tid************] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: **********[![enter image description here][1]][1]



Read the error log. There is a clear message what's wrong.

I am also adding some apache logs

All resources has to be local and inside the Maintenance folder. It seems you attempt to proxy content in case of a 503, and get connection refused.

I can assure you that all content is inside the Maintenance folder

Then the Paths in the html are wrong. You've cut off the relevant parts from the screenshot.

I already tried running the Maintenance project directly. Its working fine when I run it directly on server. When I use it on reverse proxy to show custom page on 503 error its not working.

Show us the paths then.

Updated the screenshots with paths, also the page works when I directly access it by http://localhost/Maintenance.

your index page in /Maintenance is referring to files outside of the /Maintenance folder, which in this case could be failing due to the Proxy not being up due to Maintenance. I'd first trying copying the whole of the localhost/css folder into /Maintenance and setting the base tag to be under /Maintenance, with all calls for css being not absolute but relative.

thanks for the solution @Marcel. I change the relative path of css files in index.html to /Maintenance/css/... .

It seems your paths are wrong in your html, the css's from /Maintenance/index.html are pointing to /css and not /Maintenance/css.
Your index page in /Maintenance is referring to files outside of the /Maintenance folder, which in this case could be failing due to the Proxy not being up due to Maintenance.
I'd first trying copying the whole of the localhost/css folder into /Maintenance and setting the base tag to be under /Maintenance, with all calls for css being not absolute but relative
I hope that helps.
